# Multiple single-thread binaries faster than one parallel OpenMP process?

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a relatively large C++ program that does a lot of dynamic memory allocation (size and structure are calculated at runtime; it's pointers all the way down).

The program is embarrassingly parallel, and OpenMP **does speed it up**, up to a point. However, I found that launching single-threaded binaries, and having them sync up through the file system runs faster, and slows down less as the number of cores used increases.

Is there an intuitive reason why this might happen? (sorry I don't have a code snippet.)

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, not possible to answer this without code. Any response would be pure guessing and not be helpful. See if you can distill a [mcve].

Comment: Build with OMP and profile.
It’s probably either synchronization overhead i.e. your OpenMP jobs are too small and there’re too many of them, or memory allocations. More exotic reasons are also possible, e.g. CPU cache slows down a lot when lines are shared between cores.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this, and will later try to create a small example.